# Creating a PDU to send over a network using OpenDIS

Tags: java, simulation, package

I am working with a couple of simulators, and trying to create a plug-in, that will manage the data flow over the network between the simulators (so that the amount of data sent over the network by one simulator won't flood the other simulator and cause it to crash- it will try to display any information being sent over the network that it can read).

The way the system currently works is that one of the simulators will 'package up' all of the information about every entity in the simulation and send all of the information pertaining to each entity in a single PDU. The other simulator is 'listening' to the traffic on the network, and any time it 'hears' a PDU that is in a readable format, it will display the entity in its simulation, depending on the information that is provided in the PDU.

I have a program which is receiving all of the PDUs that are being sent over a network (there are thousands every second). The PDUs hold a 'symbol', and each symbol is matched to an enumeration, which contains the information needed for the second simulator to display it in its simulation. The symbols are mapped in a .config file in the following format:

```
SFGPEVATH------G = 1 1 224 1 2 2 0
```

Everything to the left of the '=' is what the first simulator is sending out for a representation of an entity, and everything to the right of the '=' is what the second simulator is receiving to display that entity in its simulation.

When a PDU is received, I am getting the data it holds using the `getString()` method, and passing the `symbol` in as an argument, i.e.

```
String enumeration = RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(symbol);
```

I am then creating a new entity (to be displayed in the second simulator:

```
EntityType entityType = new EntityType():
```

Next, I am splitting the `enumeration` String that I've just received from the network so that I can create entities with appropriate enumerations to be displayed in the second simulator:

```
String[] parts = enumeration.split("=");
String symbolCode = parts[0];
String symbolEnumeration = parts[1];
```

and splitting up the enumeration into its separate values:

```
String[] enumerationParts = symbolEnumeration.split(" ");
```

I am then setting all of the values required to display the entity in the second simulation, by using the values received in the 'symbol' sent by the first simulation, that I've just saved in the `enumerationParts` ArrayList:

```
entityType.setDomain(Short.parseShort(enumerationParts[1]));
entityType.setCountry(Short.parseShort(enumerationParts[2]));
...
```

All in all, I am setting 8 values here using the elements of the `enumerationParts` ArrayList.

What I want to know, is how I can now bundle/ package up the EntityType object `entityType`, whose various attributes I've just set the values for, into a PDU to send it out on a different network to the one on which I am receiving all the PDUs.

Comment: Do you have two instances of NioServer?

Comment: What is NioServer? I have never heard of this, so I am not knowingly using it... unless it's something that's built into/ part of something else?

Comment: How are you receiving the data - is it through the PduMulticastReceiver?

Comment: I'm don't think I'm using a `PduMulticastReciever` at all... I'm just listening to every message on the network, and checking if each one is an Entity State PDU- if they are an ESPDU, I add them to an `ArrayList`, and unpackage them in order to use their data. If they're not an ESPDU, I just ignore them